# Why does my const reference variable, assigned via a getter that returns a const reference, not have the desired value?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Walltimes 
{
  private:
    double walltime = 0.0;

  public:
    void update_walltime(double delta)
    {
        walltime += delta;
    }

    double const& get_walltime() const
    {
        return walltime;
    }
};

int main(){
    Walltimes myObj;

    double const& t1 = myObj.get_walltime();  // Time "t1"

    myObj.update_walltime(4.78);              // Update the walltime

    double const& t2 = myObj.get_walltime();  // Time "t2"

    std::cout << "t1: " << t1 << "s\n";
    std::cout << "t2: " << t2 << "s" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

First of all, the behaviour I want (and the behaviour I *thought* I would get from running this code) is for t1 to equal 0.0 and t2 be equal to 4.78.

Instead, the output I get is:

```
t1: 4.78s
t2: 4.78s
```

When I make `t1` and `t2` have the type `double const` (so removing the `&`) I get the desired output. It also works if I instead remove the reference symbol from my `get_walltime()` declaration, but not with both references there.

It's worth noting I originally had the references there to avoid copies being made, I just wanted a getter that returns a const reference to the current value of `walltime`. I realise now that wanting the "current" walltime may require me to deprecate the references(?), as `t1` is instead returning what `walltime` ends up being after it is updated.

Obviously I can fix it with one of the solutions above, but I was wondering if anyone could kindly explain *why* this current behaviour is happening? Why does `t1` know that the walltime will eventually be 4.78? Clearly it's something to do with references and I've tried googling it, but I'm not really satisfied (it probably doesn't help that I'm relatively new to C++). Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: `t1` and `t2` are both references to the same object.  They can't possibly be different.  `update_walltime` doesn't replace `walltime` with a different object, it modifies the same object.

Comment: `t1` is a reference to the data member `walltime` and so when you wrote `myObj.update_walltime(4.78); `, you updated the data member `walltime` which means `t1` is also updated as it is an **alias** for `walltime`.

Comment: Think of references as *aliases*. Both `t1` and `t2` are aliases for the exact same `myObj.walltime` variable.

Comment: For simple native type, you don't really save much (if anything at all) by using references. Return by value (not `const`), as in `double get_walltime() const`.

Comment: The `const` references in `main()` mean that `main()` cannot change the member of `myObj` but doesn't prevent calls of other member functions (like `myObj.update_walltime(4.78)`) from directly changing that member.   If the value of that member is changed, the value accessed via references to it must also change.

Comment: By using references everywhere, you did indeed avoid copies. However, if you want `t1` and `t2` to be different, you *have* to make a copy somewhere along the way. For example, think of `t1` being a backup copy of the previous clock state.

Comment: Thanks everyone, this concept of aliases is very useful - I understand now that because `t1` is a reference to myObj's `walltime`, updating `walltime` must also update `t1`! I originally thought `t1` was only tied to the value that `walltime` had at the time of declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does t1 know that the walltime will eventually be 4.78?

Because `t1` is a reference to the data member `walltime` for object `myObj` and so when you wrote `myObj.update_walltime(4.78);` , you updated the data member `walltime` of `myObj` which means the change will be reflected in `t1` also as `t1` is an **alias** for `walltime`.

Answer (score 1):

`t1` is a *reference* to the value contained in the instance; you can't change it *through* the reference (because the reference is `const`) but the value it references is mutable. You changed that value before you printed `t1`. `t1`, not having any "value" of its own, accurately reported the value found where it references. This is how references work. If you don't want `t1` to update, don't make it a reference, so you store a copy by value.

Note that in this case, using references saved you nothing (at least on 64 bit systems). References are typically implemented under the hood with pointers (aside from when the compiler can just avoid a reference at all and just logically use the same place it refers to directly), so returning a 64 bit pointer or a 64 bit `double` changes nothing, storage-wise, and it's usually *slower* with the reference (because it has to traverse the pointer each time to find the real value).